# How can I get the current filters in javaScript in such a way that these can be passed to the back end API to generate a PDF?

Tags: powerbi, export-to-pdf, powerbi-filters

How can I get the current filters in javaScript in such a way that these can be passed to the back end, or to the javascript api to generate a PDF?

tried with report.getFilters() and report.bookmarksManager.getBookMarks() both did not return any filters